# In nifi custom processor is throwing transfer relationship not specified exception

Tags: apache-nifi, hdf

In nifi, I am creating a custom processor which reads multiple row csv data and converts each row into a json and sends.

Below is the custom processor code:
    package hwx.processors.demo;

```
import org.apache.nifi.components.PropertyDescriptor;
import org.apache.nifi.components.PropertyValue;
import org.apache.nifi.flowfile.FlowFile;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.nifi.annotation.behavior.ReadsAttribute;
import org.apache.nifi.annotation.behavior.ReadsAttributes;
import org.apache.nifi.annotation.behavior.WritesAttribute;
import org.apache.nifi.annotation.behavior.WritesAttributes;
import org.apache.nifi.annotation.lifecycle.OnScheduled;
import org.apache.nifi.annotation.documentation.CapabilityDescription;
import org.apache.nifi.annotation.documentation.SeeAlso;
import org.apache.nifi.annotation.documentation.Tags;
import org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException;
import org.apache.nifi.processor.io.OutputStreamCallback;
import org.apache.nifi.processor.io.StreamCallback;
import org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor;
import org.apache.nifi.processor.ProcessContext;
import org.apache.nifi.processor.ProcessSession;
import org.apache.nifi.processor.ProcessorInitializationContext;
import org.apache.nifi.processor.Relationship;
import org.apache.nifi.processor.util.StandardValidators;
import org.apache.nifi.stream.io.BufferedOutputStream;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

@Tags({"example"})
@CapabilityDescription("Provide a description")
@SeeAlso({})
@ReadsAttributes({@ReadsAttribute(attribute="", description="")})
@WritesAttributes({@WritesAttribute(attribute="", description="")})
public class MyProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    public static final PropertyDescriptor EXPECTED_JSON = new PropertyDescriptor
            .Builder().name("EXPECTED_JSON")
            .displayName("EXPECTED_JSON")
            .description("EXPECTED_JSON")
            .required(true)
            .addValidator(StandardValidators.NON_EMPTY_VALIDATOR)
            .build();

    public static final PropertyDescriptor DELIMITER = new PropertyDescriptor
            .Builder().name("DELIMITER")
            .displayName("DELIMITER")
            .description("DELIMITER For CSV")
            .required(true)
            .addValidator(StandardValidators.NON_EMPTY_VALIDATOR)
            .build();

    public static final Relationship SUCCESS = new Relationship.Builder()
            .name("SUCCESS")
            .description("Example relationship")
            .build();

    private List<PropertyDescriptor> descriptors;

    private Set<Relationship> relationships;

    @Override
    protected void init(final ProcessorInitializationContext context) {
        final List<PropertyDescriptor> descriptors = new ArrayList<PropertyDescriptor>();
        descriptors.add(EXPECTED_JSON);
        descriptors.add(DELIMITER);
        this.descriptors = Collections.unmodifiableList(descriptors);

        final Set<Relationship> relationships = new HashSet<Relationship>();
        relationships.add(SUCCESS);
        this.relationships = Collections.unmodifiableSet(relationships);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Relationship> getRelationships() {
        return this.relationships;
    }

    @Override
    public final List<PropertyDescriptor> getSupportedPropertyDescriptors() {
        return descriptors;
    }

    @OnScheduled
    public void onScheduled(final ProcessContext context) {

    }

    final AtomicReference<String> value = new AtomicReference<>();
    @Override
    public void onTrigger(final ProcessContext context, final ProcessSession session) throws ProcessException {
        FlowFile flowFile = session.get();
        if ( flowFile == null ) {
            return;
        }
        //String r=context.getProperty("MY_PROPERTY").toString();
        //Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$(\\d)+");
        session.read(flowFile, in -> {
            String r="";
            try {
            r= IOUtils.toString(in);
            /*if(r.contains("$"))
            {
                r=r.replaceAll("\\$", "\\\\\\$");
            }*/
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                getLogger().error(e.getMessage() + " exception.", e);
            }

            String[] test=r.split(context.getProperty("DELIMITER").toString());
            for(String s1:test){
            try{
            String[] s=s1.replaceAll("\r\n", " ").split(" ");
            String[] s2=s1.split(",");
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$(\\d)+");
            String text=context.getProperty("EXPECTED_JSON").toString();
            Matcher m = pattern.matcher(text);
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            while (m.find()) {
                if(Integer.parseInt(m.group(1))>s2.length)
                {
                    m.appendReplacement(sb, "");
                }
                else{
                m.appendReplacement(sb, s2[Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)) - 1]);
                }
            }
            m.appendTail(sb);
            value.set(sb.toString());
            sendRecord(session,flowFile);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                getLogger().error(e.getMessage() + " Routing to failure.", e);
            }
            }
        });

    }

    public void sendRecord(final ProcessSession session,FlowFile flowFile)
    {
        flowFile = session.write(flowFile, new OutputStreamCallback() {
            @Override
            public void process(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
                out.write(value.get().getBytes());
            }
        });
        session.transfer(flowFile,SUCCESS);
        session.commit();
        }
}
```

[image]
Below is the custom processor configuration here in EXPECTED_JSON user will add JSON payload required and custom processor will replace $1 by first position element of csv record,$2 by second like that. So, each row of csv has to be converted as seperate json and send.

**EXPECTED_JSON payload:{"test1":"$1","test2":"$2","test3":"$3","test4":"$4"}**
[image]

exception from custom processor:

```
2019-05-10 19:40:40,239 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-10] hwx.processors.demo.MyProcessor MyProcessor[id=a211cdad-016a-1000-7505-c725dfdbe9da] MyProcessor[id=a211cdad-016a-1000-7505-c725dfdbe9da] failed to process session due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.FlowFileHandlingException: StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=9e2161a0-517a-4c5e-bee2-30a7f22f42f7,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1557497351911-1, container=default, section=1], offset=0, length=533],offset=0,name=9e2161a0-517a-4c5e-bee2-30a7f22f42f7,size=533] transfer relationship not specified; Processor Administratively Yielded for 1 sec: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.FlowFileHandlingException: StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=9e2161a0-517a-4c5e-bee2-30a7f22f42f7,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1557497351911-1, container=default, section=1], offset=0, length=533],offset=0,name=9e2161a0-517a-4c5e-bee2-30a7f22f42f7,size=533] transfer relationship not specified
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.FlowFileHandlingException: StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=9e2161a0-517a-4c5e-bee2-30a7f22f42f7,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1557497351911-1, container=default, section=1], offset=0, length=533],offset=0,name=9e2161a0-517a-4c5e-bee2-30a7f22f42f7,size=533] transfer relationship not specified
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.checkpoint(StandardProcessSession.java:271)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.commit(StandardProcessSession.java:342)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:28)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1162)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:209)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
    at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-05-10 19:40:40,239 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-10] o.a.n.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask Administratively Yielding MyProcessor[id=a211cdad-016a-1000-7505-c725dfdbe9da] due to uncaught Exception: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.FlowFileHandlingException: StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=9e2161a0-517a-4c5e-bee2-30a7f22f42f7,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1557497351911-1, container=default, section=1], offset=0, length=533],offset=0,name=9e2161a0-517a-4c5e-bee2-30a7f22f42f7,size=533] transfer relationship not specified
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.FlowFileHandlingException: StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=9e2161a0-517a-4c5e-bee2-30a7f22f42f7,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1557497351911-1, container=default, section=1], offset=0, length=533],offset=0,name=9e2161a0-517a-4c5e-bee2-30a7f22f42f7,size=533] transfer relationship not specified
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.checkpoint(StandardProcessSession.java:271)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.commit(StandardProcessSession.java:342)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:28)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1162)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:209)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
    at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: How is this related to hdf?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that's because you use `session.write`, `session.transfer`, `session.commit` while `session.read` not finished

you have to place those operations sequentially

btw, you could use `session.write` instead of `session.read`+`session.write`

```java
flowFile = session.write(flowFile, new StreamCallback(){
    void process(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException{ 
        // ... read & write flowfile
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you can you please explain how can i use session.write  instead of session.read+session.write by using my code.

Comment: the part of code in my answer. just read from input stream and write to output.

Comment: I wanted to read csv from input stream, create separate json for each row of csv and send. But here flow I take one session.write instead of session.read+session.write then how can i pass multiple flow files.

Comment: then this is not for you. you have to create new flowfiles and remove old one. and i don't see this in your code. why you are not using standard processors for this?

Comment: i am beginner to nifi and there are some use cases i need to use like this. can you just explain how I can achieve this(creating new flows). Using execute script I got the solution but I wanted in custom processor.

Comment: your code looks similar to SplitContent processor. Just look how it implemented. Search for `session.clone`. https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/SplitContent.java